# Button is not showing using BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

Can anyone give me a hint why my button is not visible when I use BorderPane Layout? Everything else is working perfect but button doesn't show up.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class App extends Application{  

  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Button btn1=new Button("Log In");
        btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("You're logged in");
            }
        });
        BorderPane root=new BorderPane();

    Glow glow = new Glow();
    glow.setLevel(100);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1250,750);           //Fill of the screen
    rect.setFill(Color.grayRgb(60));

    Polygon poly = new Polygon();                               //shape
    poly.setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);
    poly.setEffect(glow);
    poly.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            00.0,375.0,
            950.0,750.0,
            1150.0,750.0,
    });

    Polygon poly2 = new Polygon();
    poly2.setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);
    poly2.setEffect(glow);
    poly2.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            1250.0,375.0,
            100.0,750.0,
            300.0,750.0,
    });
  Scene scene=new Scene(root,1250,750);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ROXXY");

        root.getChildren().addAll(rect,poly, poly2, btn1);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: don't add it via borderPane.getChildren().add (they are ignored in layout), instead add via setBottom/Center etc

Comment: Add the button using the `setCenter` method as @kleopatra said, but don't forget to remove it from `addAll`, or it will cause an exception.

Comment: @adxl good catch :)

Comment: Ok, It works now, thanks guys a lot!